# Use interface to pass data in Kotlin

Tags: interface, kotlin, initialization

I need to pass data to class from activity. I use interface, but i have problem with initialization.

My class:

```
class Methods  {

fun processingResponse(finalMessage: String) {

    var mcontext: Context? = null
    var message : Message =  Message()
    var access = "Access Granted"
    var out = "Logged"
    var Stateconnect = false
    var safetyCheck = 0

    if (access in finalMessage) {

        val msg = finalMessage.split("=", ":")
        accessLevel = msg[0]
        sessionId = msg[1].toInt()
        safetyCheck = msg[2].toInt()
        var namePlc = msg[3]

        interfaceData.sendData("Connect")
        //Stateconnect = true
    } else if (out in finalMessage) {

        interfaceData.sendData("Disconnect")

        println("log out okey")

    }
}}
```

My interface:

```
interface SendDataInterface {fun sendData(str: String )}
```

and My activity:

```
class LoginIn : AppCompatActivity(), SendDataInterface {

override fun sendData(str: String)
{

    var handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.post( Runnable() {

        fun run() {
            buttonChange(str)
        }
    })} fun buttonChange(str : String) {

        if (str == "Connect") {
            Connection.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            Connection.setText("Disconnection")
            loadMaintenancePage()

        } else if (str == "Disconnect") {

            Connection.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            Connection.setText("Connection")
        }
    }
```

}

The error that i have is the interface isn't initialize.
How I can initialize the interface?

Comment: How are you injecting `interfaceData ` into processingResponse . It might be that by the time the call is made to interfaceData.sendData , your LoginIn activity is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of SendDataInterface in your class Methods.

Answer (score 0):

var interfaceData:SendDtaInterface=Object:SendDtaInterface{
override fun sendData("Connect"){

}
}
interfaceData.sendDat("connect")`enter code here`

Comment: Please add some explanation to what your code does, also format it properly.